# PHP Dynamic Duck Typing Without Eval

Tags: php, eval, duck-typing

Example:

```
<?php
class a{
    public function func(){
        return "a";
    }
}

class b{
    public function func(){
        return "b";
    }
}

$input = "a"; // Would come from user input

eval('$duck = new '.$input.'();');
$duck->func(); // Returns a in this case
```

Is there any way I can do this without using `eval()`?

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course you can do it without `eval()`. PHP will take either a string containing the class name or the literal as an argument to the `new` operator.

```
$duck = new $input; // parentheses are optional
echo $duck->func();
```

Comment: I've been coding PHP for almost a year now, and PHP OOP for about a month. I never expected it to be that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by storing the class name into a string, for example :

```
$input = "a";
$duck = new $a();
if(is_callable($duck',"func")){
   $duck->func();
}
```

would work